# What does PROC mean?

Tags: terminology

I understand what it is, like an item proc that delivers an effect on hit for example. But what does PROC actually mean? Does it stand for something or is it short for another word?

Comment: @MBraedley did you even read that question, it doesn't even mention PROC...the 4 letter combination of PROC is no where in that question...

Comment: Related: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4363/on-the-meaning-of-proc

Comment: @Paralytic: Which is why you edit it in.  Just because `x` is not contained in a list that should contain `x` doesn't mean this isn't a dupe.

Comment: @MBraedley just as easy as answering this question, but no everyone wants to just shut down everyone this has become a site of trolls when it used to be a site of delightfully helpful ppl.

Comment: @Paralytic MBraedley is right. That question SHOULD answer this one, so its a dupe. It's up to us as experience users to make the situation right, hence EDIT. I'm doing it now.

Comment: @Mbraedley sadly, this question isn't about the *definition*, but about the *etymology*, so it's not a dupe. That says, said etymology is contentious and generally lost, so this question will attract a lot of bad answers. :(

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz It actually seems to me like the question proper is asking about the definition, whereas the answer explains that as well as the etymology. The answer is good and deserves upvotes, but I feel like the question itself should still be closed as a dupe.

Comment: @schism read the first sentence of the question; he acknowledges that he knows what the term means, but is unclear as to whether it is an acronym or abbreviation - etymology, not usage.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Well questions about etymology should be migrated to english.SE ;-)

Comment: @Zommuter I would not be opposed to this. I don't like this question, I just don't think it's a dupe.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Hm, while apart from the short definition in the other answer this appears to yield for opinion-based answers, I hardly can make my case in [Is a question a duplicate just because it asks for something that can be part of another question's answer?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/is-a-question-a-duplicate-just-because-it-asks-for-something-that-can-be-part-of) inconsequentially - then again I don't want to see this site suffocating in questions asking for each and every term...

Comment: Dan, do you actually ask about the meaning of PROC in LoL or is there a different context? You should add a game specific tag to clarify **edit** Never mind... @LessPop_MoreFizz Why did you remove the tag? If the question is really about a more generic expression "PROC" than the one from LoL, this question would probably be closed as "too broad"

Comment: @zommuter I removed the tag because the term means the same thing and has the same etymology everywhere. We wouldn't tag "what does Circle-strafing mean" with [tag:counterstrike] either I hope.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz To be honest I never heard the expression PROC anywhere before, and according to the [meta post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4363/on-the-meaning-of-proc) Fluttershy linked to this may even be game-dependent - the "dupe" actually states `Proc Refers to an item's or an abilities' activation, usually but not always based on % chance. Examples include Phage's Slow, Vi's Denting Blows, Caitlyns Headshot, etc.`. I agree that circle-strafing couldn't be tagged counterstrike, but there's a FPS one for that...

Comment: @zommuter It's *not* game dependent. Go to the forum for *any* MMO and you'll see the term in wide use. Also, in spite of OP's ignorance, it's just 'proc'. It doesn't need all caps. It should also be noted that the question that this was duped to was *edited to include 'proc'* **in response to this question being posted**.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I see - I'm not much into MMO so I didn't know. Well, voting to reopen then

Comment: Given we already have the word "trigger" in English, it's puzzling what people think the imaginary word "proc" brings to the table.

Answer (score 25):

Apparently, there are several definitions available.

1) It stands for "Programmed Random OCcurence". This term pretty accurately describes the event itself, both its randomness and the fact there is some special effect.

2) Short for Procedure, or Special Procedure. Coming far back from the old text MUDs (Multi-user dungeons), it stands for the special procedure, or event, that happens when the stars are right and a random number fits some required range.

Comment: Regarding "procedure", that's 20th century programming terminology for what you'd now more usually call a "function", so in older code you could be literally calling a procedure. It specifically refers to an ordered sequence of actions, so it would be highly applicable (from a developer's point of view) where the game needs to step through a particular set of states - animation, attack cycles, whatever.

Answer (score 6):

Being a programmer, I think of it as derived from "Procedure" (though what I think doesn't really affect where it originally came from).
As an example, say you attack an enemy unit. As your attack strikes, an on-hit event occurs and all your items and abilities execute their procedures for that event - they "proc".

Programmed Random OCcurence doesn't sit well with me, especially w.r.t. LoL - does LoL even have any random procs left? The acronym may well be etymological, but even if that's the case it no longer has anything to do with the term "proc" as it's being used today.

Since "Procedure" is a bit technical and "PROc" has lost any potential meanting, I don't think "proc" should be considered an abbreviation or acronym for anything - it's just jargon.

Comment: I suppose that in the case of non-random procs, it could simply be "PRogrammed OCcurrence", if you really wanted to backronymize it.

Comment: "it's just jargon", agree.  I think the majority of "proc" users do not know/care/agree on the origin of proc.

Answer (score 2):

An answer by way of example:

Let's say that I have a sword which does 16 damage but is also endowed with a 50% chance to freeze on hit.

I wouldn't say: "I `proc` the sword."
But if it hit I would say: "The sword `proc`ed."
Using the term loosely in this situation I might even say: "I `proc`ed the freeze."

It's worth mentioning in an answer that this is related to: [On the meaning of 'proc'](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4363/on-the-meaning-of-proc)

[Blem](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/13269/blem)'s answer in there mentions: http://www.wowwiki.com/Proc

Which I think probably has the best exposition on a definition.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, the word "Proc" is short for the word "Process". As in you hit, and the effect is processed upon hitting, and that applies its special effect.