# Can Mehrunes Razor accidentally kill a follower?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Lydia and I are best pals fighting hordes and hordes of the undead and the living using our blades! The only problem with Lydia is she comes close to me whenever I spam my M1-crusade and some hit hers. This was not a problem when I used some basic swords and so on... But now I use *Mehrunes Razor* as my primary weapon...

So my question:

**Is it possible for the Mehrunes Razor to instantly kill a follower?**

*Specific question:* **If the Mehrunes Razor procs when I hit my follower Lydia, will she go to the tired/defeated stage or will it instantly kill her?**

I'm afraid my spamming blows could one day kill Lydia when she gets in the way... :(

I have been using Mehrunes Razor for some time now and I have accidentally hit Lydia rarely (say 10 blows or so) and she survived. But considering the Razor has a low chance to proc, I think I (and Lydia) might just have been lucky....

**Game status:** No mods. Official add-ons installed (Hearthfire, Dawnguard).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes it is possible to proc on followers.** So be careful.

https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/5csfpo/if_you_have_a_follower_and_use_mehrunes_razor_be/

Comment: Using the add-ons, It is possible to get the ability to not harm followers through a black book.

Comment: It can proc, but even that thread says it is a hoax.  Can't kill essentials.

Comment: What does "proc" mean?

Comment: @Thunderforge Proc is chance to hit...

Comment: @Softability Doesn't the follower follow the stages (i.e) tired/recovering stage and then if we attack when she is in that stage, she dies. Does the razor bypass this stage and lead to instant death?

Comment: If irc, lydia is an essential so she cant be killed. While lydia can be tired/recovering(kneeling) she will just stay like that until the fight is over.

Comment: @NikhilEshvar I forgot exactly which Bethesda game that did this.  I think it was Fallout New Vegas.  It definitely wasn't Skyrim though.

Comment: @Thunderforge "Proc" means to have a conditional effect occur. The condition is often something like random chance, though it could be something like "only works against specific monster types" or something. See [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/122163/145980) for more details.

Comment: @Nelson and NikhilEshvar non-essential followers in Skyrim do follow that pattern. They will go down (kneeling) and enemies will not intentionally target them. They die very easily when in that stage from AoE damage or friendly fire.

Comment: @Paul Sorry but you're remembering the wrong game, or you modded your game.  You can't kill essential characters in vanilla Skyrim that way.  You should test it using no mods, not even the unofficial patches.

Comment: @Nelson For sure. That's why I said non-essential followers.

Comment: You can proc the follower, but the answer itself doesn't actually answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

Specific to your scenario;

You cannot kill an essential character.   Lydia can be essential or not, depending on your mods and console commands.  You can "proc" her with the Razor, but she will only go into the crippled state.  The Razor has an enchantment on it which, with certain unlocking mods, can be placed on other things.  It's functionally like any other enchantment, which can harm an NPC but only kill if they aren't essential.  There are also two characters in a DLC which have a specific immunity to the effect.

The only thing that can kill an essential character is a scripted event.  The essential state of a character can also change, and often does once quests tied to them are complete, or if the quest requires you kill the essential character.